# Issues with Ivpack and Stargazer

Tags: r, economics

Cluster.robust.se seems to change the data type of the iv regression and cuts observations counts with stargazer, any tips for getting them back in?

Example:

```
library(ivpack)
library(stargazer)
df<- tibble(
  indiv_id = sample(10, 100, rep = TRUE),
  group_id = sample(10, 100, rep = TRUE),
  cluster= sample(2,100,rep=TRUE)
)
iv<-cluster.robust.se(ivreg(df$indiv_id~df$group_id),df$cluster)
stargazer(iv,
          type="text")
```

Answer (score 1):

What's going on is that `cluster.robust.se()` changes the class of your model from `ivreg` to `coeftest`. Check this out:

```
> class(ivreg(df$indiv_id~df$group_id))
[1] "ivreg"

> class(iv)
[1] "coeftest"
```

These are two different objects, so stargazer gives different results, excluding observation counts from the `coeftest` output.

One possible solution is to include both objects in the same table, like this:

```
iv<-cluster.robust.se(ivreg(df$indiv_id~df$group_id),df$cluster)
myivreg <- ivreg(df$indiv_id~df$group_id)

stargazer(myivreg, iv, type="text")
```